# Why is this edit getting continually rejected?

Tags: discussion, edits, editor

I asked a question on SO, and I received an answer which had a few small spelling and syntax errors:

Original:

```
CREATE TRIGER "tsvfix" ON UPDATE OR INSERT TO "sample_ts_vec" EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvfix;
```

So I edited it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "tsvfix" BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON "sample_ts_vec" EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvfix();
```

But for some reason my edit keeps getting rejected? Am i missing something, and if not, how can we open up a clearer dialog between the editor and the editor reviewer?

Here's the question:
[Setting up postgres ts_vector column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772489/setting-up-postgres-ts-vector-column)

Comment: Because you shouldn't make code edits. Let the one posting edit it and notify him using a comment. You need to be an expert in the tag to know exactly what your change does, and most of the reviewers aren't, so they decline (they should skip of course).

Comment: Fair, and thanks for telling me. Still, this begs the question that for a user new to this etiquette (like myself) shouldn't there me some kind of dialog? E.g. I should get a more relevant explanation like the one you provided when my edit gets rejected? This is the message I have been getting: "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit"

Comment: @mgoldwasser: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work.

Comment: You only made the suggestion twice; the first time round it was [rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6653212); the [second suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6654042) is still being reviewed. That is hardly enough data points to conclude that it keeps being rejected. But have *no idea* if your edit is correct, and as a reviewer I'd rejected it on those grounds.

Comment: @martijn-pieters thanks for the explanation. To be clear, 4 reviewers have rejected it so far, but I'm confused why people are not just skipping it if they do not feel comfortable reviewing the edit? Just because someone lacks experience with postgres doesn't mean my edit is incorrect?

Comment: @mgoldwasser: because we cannot assume to know how many people would be qualified to review that *and* trust that there will be enough of those reviewing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If someone is not qualified to review it they should skip it, not reject it.  It is an incorrect review action to reject an edit that you don't understand the appropriateness of.

Comment: @Servy: and what'll happen is that unqualified people will find the review (as the queue is so short and everyone is hunting for badges) and approve it instead. If the code was this badly spelled in *my field of expertise* I might have downvoted the answer instead and / or written a better one without all those mistakes, rather than edit the post.

Comment: @Servy: but sure, I'd skip this specific review; it looks like a reasonable edit that I cannot otherwise judge on the merits. I *do* worry that there won't be anyone else to review it either, or that it'll just get robo-approved instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters In this particular case, the edit is completely valid and *should* be approved, so approving it is *the correct course of action*.

Comment: @Servy: glad you are so confident. I'm not going to spend the time to look up the syntax and validate the change, myself, however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Then you're more than welcome to skip it.  I spent all of 60 seconds looking up the syntax for creating a trigger and found the edit to have been correct.  If you don't want to spend that time, you're welcome to skip it.  Rejecting the post because you're unwilling to spend the few seconds to go look it up is the incorrect review action.  Rejecting a post that you were too lazy to actually review is simply not acceptable.

Comment: @Servy: I already stated that I would skip the edit. This is a small enough edit that a good reviewer can indeed verify the syntax changes as needed. There are other code-only edits that are larger and in more esoteric places, and I have seen changes to my answers approved that were *entirely wrong*. Just not in syntax, but in code use. Reviewers are simply not equipped to judge code changes, even if they think they are.

Comment: @Servy: [example edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5217687) that was *entirely* missing the mark. Why the edit was approved I still cannot fathom.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's an edit that's just adding in a large block of new content, rather than fixing a typo in existing content.  It should be rejected for that reason regardless of its technical accuracy.  And regardless, the existence of other edits that aren't correct doesn't mean that you should reject every single code edit just in case it might be wrong.

Comment: @Servy: it was the most memorable change that I could recall from my 12000 answers; I'm sure I can find 'typo' corrections too. Code changes require more than knowing the syntax. They require understanding that most reviewers do not have, and thus my advice to people *suggesting* edits, is to stay away from code changes.

Comment: If the edit is skipped until somebody proficient enough to judge its quality then everything should be fine. However I wonder what happens if someone else with editing privileges edits in the meantime. Does the suggested edit then automatically get rejected?

Comment: @Trilarion: If they *start* editing after the suggestion was received, they will not be able to edit but to review (where they might decide to also edit and thus insta-reject/approve). Otherwise, they won't know about the edit and it will thus be rejected without prejudice as "edit conflict".